# How to bring similar cases in a single line in sql and different cases in different lines?

Tags: sql, hive, logic, etl

I have two tables of students, table 1 has personal information and table 2 has additional information on the times he borrowed books at school.

Table 1:

```
* doc_part1: id part 1
* doc_part2: id part 2
* doc_part2: id part 3
doc_all: join id1+id2+id3
profile: student profile
++ date_update_login: date when student updated login
date: date when the student entered the school
```

```
doc_part1.doc_part2;doc_parte2;doc_all;perfil;date_update_login;date
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2020-01-01;2020-01-01 (Case 1)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2020-06-28;2020-01-01 (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile2;2020-12-07;2020-01-01 (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2021-04-22;2020-01-01 (Case 1)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2021-11-04;2020-01-01 (Case 1)
```

Table 2:

```
* doc_part1: id part 1
* doc_part2: id part 2
* doc_part2: id part 3
doc_all: join id1+id2+id3
++ borrow_book: date when the student borrowed a school book
```

```
doc_part1;doc_part2;doc_parte2;doc_all;borrow_book
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;2020-06-28; (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;2020-12-07; (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;2022-01-05; (Case 3)
```

output:

```
doc_part1.doc_part2;doc_parte2;doc_all;perfil;date_update_login;borrow_book;date
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2020-01-01;null;2020-01-01 (Case 1)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile1;2020-06-28;2020-06-28;2020-01-01 (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;profile2;2020-12-07;2020-12-07;2020-01-01 (Case 2)
987654321;5672;12;987654321567212;null;null;2020-12-07;2020-01-01 (Case 3)
```

With these two tables, I need to bring 3 cases into a final table:

```
Case 1: Cases where the student just updated the login without borrowing the school book
Case 2: Cases where the student updated the login and borrowed the school book (on the same date)
Case 3: Cases where the student borrowed the school book and did not update the login
```

table major keys are marked with: marked with `*`
the dates that can be used to cross: marked with `++`

How can I do this in SQL?

[image]

With the example above, I would like help to get the 3 outputs using the 2 tables mentioned. I already resorted to the GPT chat, but I'm still having difficulties.

Comment: Please provide your data as tabular text rather than as an image, which we can't easily consume.

Comment: @GMB ok, i just put your suggestion for improvement

Comment: for `profile1`, there are serveral `case 1`s.  is there any specific logic you choose only one case for the output?

Comment: The profile is just the profile, it is standard on the table. example: cool student, rebel, studious (fake example) @Jaytiger